# How could I check if a differential equation crosses a specific value?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, rule

I'm designing a magnetic field to simulate relativistic speeds in a small cyclotron. I need to see if the ratio -R/B * dB/dR crosses 0.2 in a certain range, and right now I'm trying to do that by plotting it and looking at the graph. All of my code is working perfectly, except that last line- I'm getting an empty plot. Does anyone see what's wrong there?

Just to be clear, in math notation, I need to plot R versus -R/Bfieldbyradius(R) * Bfieldbyradius'(R), and ensure it doesn't hit the value 0.2 on various intervals.

```
ClearAll[b]
q = 1.6*10^-19
c = 299792458
m0 = 1.6726231*10^-27
b = 1
originalGap = 0.051181/2
scalefactor = 1/6
r = (R/scalefactor)
v = (b c q r)/Sqrt[(b^2 q^2 r^2 + c^2 m0^2)]
a = Solve[q*b == lorentz*m0*v/r, lorentz]
frequencybyradius = (q*b/(lorentz*m0*2*Pi)) /. a
Bfieldbyradius = b/lorentz /. a
Gapbyradius = originalGap*lorentz /. a
Plot[Gapbyradius, {R, 0, 1/6}, AspectRatio -> 1,     
    AxesLabel -> {R, Gap }, ClippingStyle -> None, PlotRange -> {0, .03}]
Plot[(-R/Bfieldbyradius)*Derivative[1][Bfieldbyradius /. a], {R, 0, 
    1/6}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the last line with

```
temp = D[Bfieldbyradius /. a, R]
Plot[(-R/Bfieldbyradius) * temp, {R, 0, 1/6}]
```

I don't know exactly why your code doesn't work but it is related to the use of a wrong argument for `Derivative[1][...]` and evaluating within `Plot` (as opposed to doing it outside first) the derivative of a function whose variable being differentiated is the same symbol as that used by `Plot`.

Comment: So, instead of Derivative[1], I can just say D? Can that be used repeatedly/recursively? Why did my solution not work?

Comment: `D` and `Derivative` are different. Check the documentation. As an example, `D[Sin[x], x]` is equivalent to `Derivative[1][Function[x, Sin[x]]][x]`. Normally I guess one wouldn't want to use `Derivative` unless s/he knows what s/he's doing. Also, it's generally a good practice to evaluate differentiation before putting it in `Plot` to avoid complications.

Comment: I used Derivative successfully to define a Taylor sum symbolically last week, but it just didn't work this time. Weird. Thanks!